# Expand last treeview node state after tree refresh(sort) C++/CLI VS2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, treeview

I need to expand treeview in state before tree resort .When I delete node from Treeview , I have to do Sort , after this tree becomes collapsed, but I need to return to state before deleting item ( expand parent of deleted node ).
Thx in advance .

Comment: So, save the parent handle, remove child node, sort, then expand parent. What's the problem?

Comment: Hard to imagine how a tree could get unsorted after deleting a node.  Delete the Sort() call.

Comment: I havae tried to save parent of removed node , but after resorting , as I see , method sort created a new tree with new nodes, so I get access violation . I need to sort it because tree is connected with list in heap.